# htaccess RewriteRule gets error 500 with $1 for remapping subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a shared hosting who points the main domain - mydomain.com and a subdomain - beta.mydomain.com - to the same folder public_html.

The structure of this hosting is:

```
/
a
b
public_html
 -a
 -b
 -.htaccess
```

The folder `a` and `b` inside `public_html` point to the respective folders in the root.

On the `.htaccess` file, there are these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Subdomain rule#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b/otherfolder/$1 [NC,L]

#Main domain rule#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a/otherfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Actually, when I visit the main domain, the *Main domain rule* matches and it shows the right page.

When I visit the subdomain, the *Subdomain rule* matches and it returns error 500; however, removing the `$1` on `/b/otherfolder/$1`, it shows the index file on that folder (of course, the page can't load the right js or css files).

Questions:

1. How can I avoid the error 500 and let the `Subdomain rule` work as well as the other one?
2. How can I enable the error log for the server/htaccess?
   I read about the ErrorLog directive, however my search only referred to the PHP.

Comment: "The folder `a` and `b` inside `public_html` point to the respective folders in the root." - By "root", do you mean the directory _above_ the document-root? (Assuming `/public_html/` is the document-root?) (How is that implemented? An `Alias` in the server config? Symlink?) So, `public_html/a` and `public_html/b` are not actual physical folders? Just wondering how this is relevant to the question? And how does `/otherfolder` fit into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `500` because of infinite looping. Which is happening because subdomain rewrite is unconditional as it keeps rewriting to `/b/otherfolder/`.

You can have following rules:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

#Subdomain rule#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/b/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b/otherfolder/$1 [NC,L]

#Main domain rule#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(a|b)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ a/otherfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Note addition of a condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/b/ [NC]` that stops this rewrite when URI starts with `/b/`.

Comment: Still no working. Do you have any answers for the question 2? It would be easier to catch the error and finding a solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: There is no directive to enable `error.log` in .htaccess. It should be enabled using `ErrorLog` directive in Apache config.

Comment: You probably need another condition on the "Main domain rule" to match the main domain (or _not_ the subdomain, or perhaps `!^/b/`), otherwise, requests for the subdomain will likely end up being rewritten a second time to `a/otherfolder/b/otherfolder/...`. (Or perhaps just use the `END` flag on the first rule?)

Comment: Yup you are right @MrWhite I have made a correction in 2nd rule to skip it for `/a/` and `/b/`. Thanks so much for your insight

Comment: The suggestion of @MrWhite worked. I realised what missed to accomplish my needs. The htaccess is so messy...